# What is the best way to set a timeout condition for functions decorated with @run_on_executor in Tornado?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

What would be the best approach for setting a timeout condition on a task/function that's been submitted to a ThreadPoolExecutor using tornado.concurrent's @run_on_executor decorator? Example Tornado handler below:

```
import json
import time
import tornado.web
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from tornado.concurrent import run_on_executor


class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def initialize(self) -> None:
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)

    @run_on_executor
    def blocking_function(self) -> None:
        """ Run Blocking Function on ThreadPoolExecutor. """
        seconds = 10
        time.sleep(seconds)
        response = json.dumps({"message": f"Slept for {seconds} seconds."})
        return response

    async def get(self) -> None:
        response = await self.blocking_function()
        self.write(response)
```

Does something like `tornado.gen.with_timeout` found [here](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html) exist for @run_on_executor?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `run_on_executor` returns a `Future` object, you can use it with `gen.with_timetout`:

```
from datetime import timedelta

async def get(self):
    response = await gen.with_timeout(
                   timedelta(seconds=5),
                   self.blocking_function()
               )

    ...
```

Don't forget to handle the timeout exception.

Comment: Hey @xyres, thank you for your answer, but these options seem to provide a "call after 5 seconds" behavior, when what I'm really asking for is to "cancel after 5 seconds". So in my example, I would want the `async def get(self)` call to raise an exception if the timeout value (e.g. 5 seconds) is met. In this case it should be, because the `blocking_function()` call should take over or equal to 10 seconds to complete. I can edit the original question if you think this wasn't clear, thank you again.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the question before. I've updated my answer now. See if it helps.

Comment: Exactly what was needed, thank you!